# ローカル通知の許可が英語表記になってしまいます．

Tags: objective-c

ローカル通知を利用するアプリで初回起動時の通知許可が英語表記になってしまいます．
日本語表記に変える方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃったら，教えていただけると助かります．
よろしくお願いいたします．

Comment: 英語表記になると言うことですが、パーミッション通知のポップアップに表示される文言は大きく２つあります。タイトル部分でしょうか？本文の部分でしょうか？タイトルに関して言えば端末言語に依存するので回答の通りですが、本文に関して言えば回答は間違いで、開発者側で設定することが可能です。

Answer (score 0):

端末の設定で指定している言語が利用されるのではないでしょうか？
そのため開発者が変更できるものではないと思います。
設定アプリで以下の手順で言語を変更できるので、試してみてはいかがでしょうか。
一般(General) > 言語と地域(Language & Region) > iPhoneの使用言語(iPhone Laungage)

Answer (score 0):

1. プロジェクトナビゲーター（画面左）の上の方にあるXcodeのプロジェクトを選択し、`TARGETS`の下の`<アプリ名>`を選択して、`Info`タブを表示します。
2. `Custom macOS Application Target Properties`に`Localization native development region`という項目があるはずなので、`Value`を`Japan`に変更します。
3. `+`ボタンをクリックして、`Localizations`という項目を追加します。
4. `Localizations`の項目を展開して、`Item 0`の`Value`に`Japanese`を設定します。

これで日本語化できるはずです。

**Xcodeのプロジェクトエディター画面:**

[image: Xcodeのプロジェクトエディター画面]